# How to add dc-addons/dc-leaflet.js to an Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, dc.js

I am building an Angular app with dc and leaflet. The dc charts work fine,but on including the dc.leafletCustomChart for including the map, an error comes up saying dc.leafletCustomChart is not a function. That is because it is an extension of the dc library which is available in dc-addons.

Now I have installed dc, leaflet, dc-addons and dc.leaflet and imported d3,dc,crossfilter2,leaflet,dc-addons and dc.leaflet to the component.

I even tried going to angular-cli.json and add

`"scripts": [
          "../node_modules/dc-addons/dist/leaflet-map/dc-leaflet.js"
]`

Even then I keep getting the error dc.leafletCustomChart is not a function in Component.

Where am I going wrong? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that the script is not loading correctly due to module loader issues. Do you get an earlier error when dc-addons is loaded?

Comment: I get 2 errors: >Uncaught ReferenceError: dc is not defined >TypeError: dc.leafletCustomChart is not a function
    at AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Apparently [angular can use any module loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912855/best-module-loader-for-angular-2) so I think it's a matter of figuring out which one you're using and then making sure dc.js is listed as a dependency of dc-addons. But I really don't have any experience here, sorry.